# Responsive Menu with CSS3

Tags: jquery, css, menu, css-transitions

I have a responsive menu I'm trying to create using transitions. I've created one via jsFiddle which can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/FN37X/

The JS I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".menu-button").click(function () {
    if ($(".menu").hasClass('close') ) {
            $(".menu").removeClass('close').addClass('open');
        } 
    else if ($(".menu").hasClass('open') ) {
            $(".menu").removeClass('open').addClass('close');
        }
});
});
```

My question is,
Is it possible to have this menu, without the brief transition that appears when resizing the window width ways.

My goal is to have a responsive menu that slides down without the use of css !important (I found using toggleSlide required this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think `slideToggle()` is your best bet, so you can also remove CSS `transition` that affects the window resizing.

In your CSS remove both `.open{}` and `.close{}` styles then on your `.menu` add `display:none` and `top:50px` (height of the black `.box-menu`).

Then your script would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".menu-button").click(function(){
        $('.menu').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FN37X/2/)

Comment: The problem with this is, once you toggle it, then resize the window. Display:none is still present so no menu appears :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick solution

```
$(window).on("resize",function(event){
    $(".menu").css("display","none");

})
$(window).on("debouncedresize",function(event){
    $(".menu").css("display","block");

})
```

just include the debounce resize script in your document :
https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize/blob/master/jquery.debouncedresize.js

it took me a bit to find a solution for debounced resize though.

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/FN37X/5/

Comment: Would be perfect, but the menu appears to flicker when resized due to the timeout?

Comment: I appreciate the help, seems like a crazy amount of code for such a small 'feature' though! Wow!

Comment: just include https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize/blob/master/jquery.debouncedresize.js in your document nothing more , ofcourse you don't have to retype all this again .